# XMLHttpRequest javascript using port number

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple xhr.open/xhr.send to my node.js app and can't figure out why it isn't working. Both are running on the same server.

When I use curl to my node.js app, it returns as expected.

Javascript

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:2121/ingredients");
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr.responseText);
```

Node.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const ingredients = [
  {
      "id": "1",
      "item": "Butter"
  }
];

app.get('/ingredients', (req, res) =>{
  res.send(ingredients);
});

app.listen(2121);
```

I tried reducing my problem to its simplest form. I've been reading about CORS ad-nauseum and still can't get this to work.

I tried setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" and "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With" (and many other trial-and-errors) in my node script to no avail. I'm hoping someone has a simple solution to this. I'm not an expert in either technology.

Comment: Have you tried using [Express's CORS middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)? That would be easier than trying to add CORS headers "manually".

Comment: Thanks jubObs...i think CORS was part of my problem as well. I can't explain why using the actual ip of the server vs localhost worked, but it worked and that's good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert either but as this is an async process (may take time to complete) you have to handle the event when it happens and not right on the `console.log()` line.

So seems like that you have to add an event handler like this:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function reqListener() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
}

req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);

xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:2121/ingredients");
xhr.send();
```

It should console log when request is done.

Answer (score -1):

After much tinkering and trial and error, I finally got it to work:

Javascript snippet:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
     console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
xhr.open("GET", "https://<ip of host...not localhost>:2121");
xhr.send()
```

Node.js snippet

```
https.createServer(creds, function (req, res) {

  var headers = {};
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
  headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain";
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
  headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '86400'; // 24 hours
  headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
     console.log('In OPTIONS')
     res.writeHead(200, headers);
     res.end();
  }

  if (req.method === "GET") {
     console.log('In GET');
     res.writeHead(200, headers);
     res.end('It worked!!!!!\n')
  }
  ...
```

I guess it was 2 things:

1. I wasn't handling the pre-flight
2. All my header information was missing

Thanks for both Rodolfo and jubObs suggestions. They both helped.